# trace of $(A^k - \lambda \cdot A^{k-1})$ when $A$ is diagonalizable matrix and $\lambda$ is $A$s eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

I solved the next question: Given the matrix A:
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 6 & -3 \\ 0 & 4 & 0 \\ -3 & 6 & -3
\end{bmatrix}

Calculate $ \operatorname{trace}(A^{2018} - 4A^{2017})$. I computed it by diagonalizing $A$, $P,P^{-1}$ and then worked with $A=PDP^{-1}$ to get $P(D^{2017}(D-4I))P^{-1}$. $A$'s eigenvalues are $(4,4,-2)$.

I am searching for a better way (a theorem or a proposition) to solve the general problem for $trace(A^{k} - \lambda A^{k-1})$. Any way (or ways) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall every matrix can be upper-triangularized over an algebraically closed field, with the diagonal being the eigenvalues occuring with their algebraic multiplicities.

Thus $\operatorname{tr}(A^n)$ is the $n$-th power sum of eigenvalues of $A$ (with multiplicity), and that pretty much solved your question:
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^k-\lambda A^{k-1})=\sum \lambda_i^{k-1}(\lambda_i-\lambda)
$$
where the sum is over eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$ with multiplicity.

Comment: Why do we have a difference in our solutions? Did I miss something trivial out?

Comment: Oops, put the suffix on the wrong lambda.  Corrected.

Comment: I was wondering about the trace of the projectors; they will be all $1$ if they have multiplicity of $1$, right?

Comment: Depending on your set-up, whether your $i$-th eigenvalue is taken with or without multiplicity.  So $P_i$ is project to the 1-dimensional subspace if you repeat the $\lambda_i$ with multiplicity, or if $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$ you would project to the eigenspace $\mathcal{E}_{\lambda_i}=\ker(A-\lambda_i)$, from taking trace recovers the multiplicity of $\lambda_i$,  Either way, they give the same result.

Comment: Thank you. I just didn't know what to do with the $\text{Tr}(P_i)$ for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ is "nice enough", we can write it as
$$A=\sum\limits_{i} \lambda_i P_i$$
Where $\lambda_i$ is the $i$-th eigenvalue, and $P_i$ is the projection that belongs to $\lambda_i$.
Then we have that
$$f(A)=\sum\limits_{i} f(\lambda_i) P_i$$
So we have that
$$A^k-\lambda_j A^{k-1}=\sum\limits_{i} \lambda_i^k P_i-\sum\limits_{i} \lambda_j \lambda_i^{k-1} P_i=\sum\limits_{ i} (\lambda_i-\lambda_j)\lambda_i^{k-1} P_i$$
So
$$\text{Tr}(A^k-\lambda_j A^{k-1})=\sum\limits_{ i} (\lambda_i-\lambda_j)\lambda_i^{k-1} \text{Tr}(P_i)$$